# Are iOS apps on Apple Silicon macs capable to initiate VPN connection?

Tags: ios, vpn, apple-silicon

I am currently developing a VPN service and building apps for each platform. As a temporary solution, I decided not to build a separate Mac app and let iOS app run on Apple Silicon Macs. Is it possible for the iOS app to initiate systemwide VPN connection while running on macOS?

Comment: Are you looking for the API info and how to do this in code or simply a yes/no answer?

Comment: @fsb I assume they've already built it for iOS and are asking if it will work as-is when run on Apple Silicon. I'd expect the answer to be yes, but there are exceptions and I'm not sure if VPN connections are one of those.

Comment: I'm not looking for any API info, i just wonder will the already existing app work on apple silicon, without any modifications in the code.